# How to compare two MimeMessage.java objects to make sure they are the same?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

We are switching from an old to a new system and have one path (the new path) that is discarded until it will match the old system. The old system creates MimeMessage in a convoluted way and unfortunately MimeMessage is not just a data object(though I think it should be and wish it was).

Which data do I need to extract from MimeMessage to compare to make sure both systems are 100% exactly the same?

Better yet, is there a Helper.writeMimeToBytes(mimeMessage) that I could run on both and compare the bytes.  The writeTo method does not write headers so that is a no-go.  I need something that I can write out the MimeMessage from each system and compare and then dig into differences as well.

They really should have had a MimeMessage that is just data where equals() method works as it's better for testing too and mocking.

CORRECTION: I read the docs wrong.  this sentence "Output the message as an RFC 822 format stream, without specified headers" got me and actually meant it passes in a null array but it turns out the multipart bytes will always be difference as Bill Shannon points out in his answer below which is still an issue.  Damn MimeMessage.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Where do the "old" and "new" MimeMessages come from and where do they go? If you want to compare them to make sure both systems are the same, it sounds like there's a persistent representation of the messages. Can't you compare those? Also, you say that the writeTo() method doesn't write headers. How sure are you about that? The second overload even accepts an ignore list that is documented as "the headers to not include in the output". This wouldn't make any sense if headers were excluded from the output anyway.

Comment: edited to fix my mistake @TXN.  No, the code to create a MimeMessage is a bit convoluted so that does not really exist.  I 'think' my best bet is to serialize a MimeMessage in a way that I can compare but I really need to ensure there are no mistakes in doing so and no state is missed from the MimeMessage and writeTo does not seem to work and Object.serialize won't work and equals won't work(if it did, I might be able to writeTo and then parse and compare).  What a crappy design on java's part for this class.

Comment: Bill Shannon will certainly be the better person to answer your question, but I wouldn't panic about the task as much as you seem to. ;) I'd just compare the output of all public no-arg get*() methods. Browsing through them I have a clear impression that this will find all possible differences and possibly even create false alarms where you can adjust. I don't see this class as crappy design. Object-oriented programming was invented with the goal of combining data and business logic. In procedural programming before the separation of those had caused a lot of headache in bigger projects...

Comment: That being said, ... for your particular use case an equals() method would be great, but then again, ... how to define it? For instance: Does the order of headers or recipients matter or not? It's difficult to write such method for such complex concepts as a MimeMessage. I also see good reasons to not even try on the level of the framework.

Comment: it's not just that, creating tests that receive a MimeMessage and being able to create a MimeMessage not attached to a session make it very hard to create tests that mock the mail api such that my mock object can receive a MimeMessage and then assert it is correct is also not feasible.  in fact, you must create a wrapper that can't really be unit tested.  It's quite a bad api to mock as well.  good api design in today's world considers others mocking your apis easily.

Comment: then again, these apis were written a long long time ago too.

Comment: Absolutely! I still remember when Java was published in the late 90s, its APIs and their ease of use were simply stunning. It was so comprehensive and flexible, really world-class and a new era of application programming. In fact we should be amazed that the language is still so widely used, still fun to work with, and that many APIs survived since then, including javax.mail. This alone shows their quality and the excellence of those who wrote it. Code is never perfect in every respect, it can't be. I'd be friendly to Bill. ;)

Answer (score 0):

MimeMessage.writeTo absolutely does write the headers.

I would be shocked if two independently constructed and non-trivial MIME messages were byte-for-byte identical.  At the very least, the Message-Id should be different, as should the multipart boundary strings.

Comment: oh, I read the comment wrong in the docs "Output the message as an RFC 822 format stream, without specified headers" but that meant there was an ignore list passed in.  I forgot about the multipart boundaries....what is the best way to compare then..crap.

Comment: Holy crap Bill, you are one of the authors of that class!!! awesome.   How to compare that class properly?  or serialize and deserialize and then compare (as I need to save it from one system and another system loads it).  OR better yet, we have a belief that any 'state' objects should have equals method and should not be tied to business logic like session so they are mockable, etc.  that would be a sick change to that class.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by "the same". If you only care that they have the same structure and semantic content, you could write your own comparison method that walks the two MimeMessage objects and compares that each header and each body part has the same content.